# Starting/Stopping while loop with JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to make a program that has a toggle button (regular JButton) that when clicked, runs a while loop that runs until the button is clicked again to stop it.

I have done this, however, when I click the button, the entire JFrame freezes because of it being stuck in the while loop, as the loop will run forever until the button is pressed again. However, it is impossible to click the button again because the JFrame freezes. The button itself also just stays blue because the JFrame freezes before the colour change occurs; right before I click the button.

My code looks something like this:

```
   boolean isRunning=false;
   private void buttonClickEvent(ActionEvent evt) {                           
    if(isRunning){
        isRunning=false;
        System.out.println("Stopped running!");
        jButton.setText("Start Running");
    } else { // BELOW IS THE CODE THAT CAUSES IT TO LOCK
        isRunning=true;
        jButton.setText("Stop Routine");
        while(isRunning){
            // DO STUFF
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: I tried doing the following code (below) and it does print the text and allow the colour change to occur in the button, but the UI still freezes quickly afterward.

```
boolean isRunning=false;
   private void buttonClickEvent(ActionEvent evt) {                           
    if(isRunning){
        isRunning=false;
        System.out.println("Stopped running!");
        jButton.setText("Start Running");
    } else { // BELOW IS THE CODE THAT CAUSES IT TO LOCK
        isRunning=true;
        jButton.setText("Stop Routine");
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while(isInRoutine){
                            System.out.println("lolk");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: You do not want the loop to be in the Event Handler, otherwise the `event` would not have been handled to completion

Comment: Where would I put it? @ScaryWombat

Comment: Probably in another thread.  I can not see from this minimal code where that would be

Comment: What more would you like me to add to the code? @ScaryWombat

Comment: Also, how would I add a new thread? @ScaryWombat

Comment: A little bit here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765904/how-threadpool-re-use-threads-and-how-it-works and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790710/how-should-i-handle-multi-threading-in-java

Comment: also look at http://stackabuse.com/how-to-use-threads-in-java-swing/

Comment: `"Also, how would I add a new thread?"` -- ??? This suggests that you may be putting the "cart before the horse", that is trying to learn a complex corner of Java, here multi-threaded GUI programming, before learning the basics of Java and how to do object oriented programming with Java. Start at the beginning and learn the fundamentals first and you will avoid a host of frustrations.

Comment: I'm betting that you shouldn't even have a while loop at all, that this question is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise and that a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) would work much better.

Comment: Yes, definitely use the [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Please read the link for more on this.

Comment: As for why the GUI is freezing, please read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: These are great resources, helped me fixed the problem! And you were correct, the Swing Timer had worked flawlessly for me.